# Joined CSV table to feature class had NULL values that should not have been there

Tags: csv, attribute-joins, feature-class

This is bothering me.  I had a feature class who's join field was "double" and the field in the CSV table was also "double". Essentially the same data type.  I had about 2/3rd of the data turn out NULL when I tried to create a join.  I solved the problem by calculating a new field in both the CSV table and the feature class with the same data type (double) and it then worked.  I don't understand why it did not work in the first place. I should not have had to copy a new identical field in the feature class and CSV table to do the join

Comment: This is a fundamentals of floating-point operations topic. Joins require equivalence operators that are unreliable with double or single comparison or with string-to-binary to single or double comparison. The first rule of floating-point joins is "Don't do it"; the second rule (experts only) is "Don't do it yet."

Comment: What GIS software are you using, add a tag

Comment: ArcGIS Pro  :)  I am still having major issues with 1:1 join of an imported CSV (comma separated values) table to my feature class attribute table.  I had both data types as "double" and I ended up with most of the data as NULL again and I could not solve it like I had before when I first posted.  I am very new to this kind of thing and am very perplexed.  I read that comment about floating-point operations (I am not familiar with floating point operations).